# How to modify a form to have some field surrounded by 'Details'?

Tags: 8, forms

I created a custom content entity with Drupal Console.
Three of its fields are defined this way:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $weight++;
    $fields['picture'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('image')
      ->setLabel(t('Picture'))
      ->setSettings([
        'file_extensions' => 'gif jpeg jpg png',
        'file_directory' => 'sel',
        'alt_field_required' => 0,
      ])
      ->setCardinality(3)
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'type' => 'default',
        'weight' => $weight,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'image_image',
        'weight' => $weight,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $weight++;
    $fields['file'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('file')
      ->setLabel(t('File'))
      ->setSettings([
        'file_extensions' => 'pdf',
        'file_directory' => 'sel',
        'description_field' => TRUE,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'type' => 'file',
        'weight' => $weight,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'file',
        'weight' => $weight,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    $weight++;
    $fields['link'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('link')
      ->setLabel(t('Link'))
      ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
        'type' => 'link',
        'weight' => $weight,
      ])
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
        'type' => 'link_default',
        'weight' => $weight,
      ])
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And the corresponding form looks like this:
[image]
I would like to have the 'file' and the 'link' field in something like the 'Picture' field...
I updated `buildForm` :

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    $form = parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
    $entity = $this->entity;
    $form['link']['widget']['0']['#type'] = 'details';
    return $form;
  }
```

And I got this:
[image]

How can I do the same for the 'File' field (have it surrounded in some 'Details')?

Comment: Why is the File field different? Or do you want to put multiple elements in the same <details> element? Then you need to move the fields to the second level of the $form array inside of a details element.

Comment: I guess File field is different because of its cardinality (when I add `->setCardinality(3)` to its BaseFieldDefinition, I get the same 'Details' behavior). All I wanted is to have a common visual aspect for the three fields, whatever their cardinality. Remember that the default form has been generated by Drupal Console.

Comment: @4k4 How can I "move" the field? Let's say I add a 'details' just before with `$form['filed'] = array('#type' => 'details', '#title' => t('File'));` what am I supposed to do with `$form['file']...`?

Comment: Move it inside of the details element, see https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Details.php/class/Details/8.7.x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it this way (thanks to @4K4 to put me on the right direction):

```
$form['fileDetails'] = array(
  '#type' => 'details',
  '#title' => $this->t('File'),
  '#weight' => 8,
);
$form['file']['#group'] = 'fileDetails';

$form['link']['widget']['0']['#type'] = 'details';
```

And I get this:
[image]